# IT hardware/software maintenance software to determine dependent services

Tags: maintenance

I'm looking for software that would help finding which applications are affected by a downtime on a software or hardware component.

As an example, application A runs on server B. It needs access to database C running on server X.

The process would be to enter all the components in the software (the one I'm looking for) and one it's done, we'd need to  enter the relationships between components (which depends on which).  The goal is that when we plan downtime for maintenance reasons on one components, we want to know which applications are affected.

Comment: If you’re going to enter the information manually, this sounds like a general graph (digraph) processing problem. I can’t name anything in particular, but I’m sure there is a general graph tool that can do what you want.